# How to join multiple tables in Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have two queries that I want to join them. The first query gives me `p_sales` and `p_views` for each day and shop group as you can see below. It only shows all shop groups, but M, N, O shop groups don't have `p_sales` in those tables.

```
SELECT date,
    CASE
    WHEN shop_group = 'MM' THEN
    'M'
    WHEN shop_group = 'NN' THEN
    'N'
    WHEN shop_group = 'OO' THEN
    'O'
     WHEN shop_group = 'RR' THEN
    'R'
    END AS shop_group, 
    sum(p_sales) as p_sales,
    sum(p_views) as p_views
FROM  Z
GROUP BY  1, 2
```

Thus, the second query will give me `p_sales' for M, N, O shop groups with the following query.

```
with sales as (
    SELECT
        book_id,
        SUM(COALESCE(sales, estimated_sales)) AS p_sales
    FROM X
    WHERE DATE(date) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10' DAY
GROUP BY book_id
HAVING SUM(COALESCE(sales, estimated_sales)) >= 0
)

SELECT
    date,
    CASE
    WHEN shop_id = 1 THEN
    'M'
    WHEN shop_id = 2 THEN
    'N'
    WHEN shop_id = 3 THEN
    'O'
    END AS shop_group,
    cast(shop_id as varchar) shop_id,
    SUM(p_sales) p_sales
FROM Y
JOIN sales
ON Y.book_id = sales.book_id
WHERE date(date) = current_date - interval '10' day 
AND shop_id in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

How can I add the second query into the first one? I want to add the second query into the first one because the first query contains `p_views` for all shop groups, and `p_values` for all shops except for M, N, O shop groups. But the second query contains only `p_sales` for three shop groups (M, N, O). This is why the second query should be a subquery of the first one so that I can see all values for all shop groups.

The desired output will contain `p_views` and `p_sales` for all shop groups.

Comment: what do you mean by integrate?? do you want to add 1st query also in CTE??

Comment: I want to add the second query to the first one. @ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Answer (score 0):

are finding below like both query under the  CTE

```
  with firstQuery as
        (SELECT date,
       CASE
    WHEN shop_group = 'MM' THEN
    'M'
    WHEN shop_group = 'NN' THEN
    'N'
    WHEN shop_group = 'OO' THEN
    'O'
     WHEN shop_group = 'RR' THEN
    'R'
    END AS shop_group, 
    sum(p_sales) as p_sales,
    sum(p_views) as p_views
FROM  Z
GROUP BY  1, 2

),
sales as (
        SELECT
            book_id,
            SUM(COALESCE(sales, estimated_sales)) AS p_sales
        FROM X
        WHERE DATE(date) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10' DAY
    GROUP BY book_id
    HAVING SUM(COALESCE(sales, estimated_sales)) >= 0
    )
    
    SELECT
        date,
        CASE
        WHEN shop_id = 1 THEN
        'M'
        WHEN shop_id = 2 THEN
        'N'
        WHEN shop_id = 3 THEN
        'O'
        END AS shop_group,
        cast(shop_id as varchar) shop_id,
        SUM(p_sales) p_sales
    FROM Y
    JOIN sales
    ON Y.book_id = sales.book_id
    WHERE date(date) = current_date - interval '10' day 
    AND shop_id in (1, 2, 3)
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but this adds the first query to the second one. I would like to add the second one into the first one since I want to have p_views, and p_sales for all shop_group.

Comment: @datazang your question is not clear to me after reading your this comment

Comment: @datazang its better share sample data and expected result

Comment: I have updated the last part of my question. Is it better now?